# Is there any public api to check the adobe extract api usage programmatically?

Tags: adobe, adobe-embed-api, adobe-pdfservices

Is there any public API that allows retrieval of Adobe Extract API usage data?

I'm aware that Adobe offers a user interface for accessing usage reports, but I'm specifically looking for an API-based solution to programmatically retrieve usage information. Please let me know if you have any insights on this.

[image: Adobe Extract API Usage UI]

Thank you!
KK

I've checked out the Adobe portal, but I couldn't locate any APIs related to usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there isn't. (I work on the team and I'd like this too.)